# Can't Lock Screen Rotation From Android Manifest

Tags: android

I want to keep my app in portrait mode. With just a basic empty activity, I added the first two lines to the application info in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lxg.golf">

    <application

        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Golf">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But it still rotates to landscape on my device (Galaxy S8, Android version 9). How can I keep it in portrait orientation?

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `screenOrientation` attribute to every activity:

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation ="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```